# How to get AWT Window for JavaFX Stage?

Tags: java, javafx, awt

The Java Taskbar API includes an option for setting a Window Progress State.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Taskbar.html#setWindowProgressState(java.awt.Window,java.awt.Taskbar.State)

Unfortunately, that API is looking for a java.awt.Window. Is there a preferred API for accessing a java.awt.Window to pass to this method from a javafx.stage.Stage/Window?

Comment: awt-window != fx-window .. they have nothing in common

Comment: I know that already... that's literally the point of the question. AFAIK this means the Taskbar API is unusable with JavaFX.

Comment: "Is there a preferred API for accessing a java.awt.Window to pass to this method from a javafx.stage.Stage/Window?"

If the answer is "no" that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is admittedly a pretty gross solution, but I will leave it here if it helps.

---

## Chaining Awt, Swing, and JavaFX into a Monstrosity

As far as I am aware, this is not possible with merely JavaFX alone. However, we can make use of a few compatibilities to achieve what you want.

- JavaFX has compatibility with Java Swing: See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) for examples.
- Java Swing has compatibility with Awt: A few Java Swing classes extend [`java.awt.Window`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) for compatibility purposes, which is accepted by the method you linked - [`setWindowProgressState​(Window,Taskbar.State state)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Taskbar.html#setWindowProgressState(java.awt.Window,java.awt.Taskbar.State)). Instances of the following `javax.swing` classes can be passed to the method you linked: [`javax.swing.JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), [`javax.swing.JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), [`javax.swing.JWindow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html), [`javax.swing.Popup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/Popup.html)

By chaining interoperability with the various Java UI frameworks, you can set the windows Taskbar state.

Here is a demonstration:

```java
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // initialize a Swing application
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JavaFX with Swing abuse");

        // create a Swing compatible JavaFX container
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        // initialize JavaFX container
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        // add elements
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);

        // configure Swing JFrame
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // use Awt compatibility with Swing
        Taskbar taskbar = Taskbar.getTaskbar();
        taskbar.setWindowProgressState(frame, Taskbar.State.ERROR);
        taskbar.setWindowProgressValue(frame, 50);
    }
}
```

On Windows 10, this is correctly displaying the Taskbar progress state:
[image: a monstrosity]

---

## Limitations

I cannot say that I *recommend* this, but regardless, it is possible. There might be a few limitations, however:

- This initializes almost every Java UI framework's subsystem, which could have significant processing and memory overheads. Mixing the various Java UI frameworks is generally ill-advised for this reason.
- Using Java Swing to render your JavaFX application might have serious drawbacks relating to performance or even compatibility with the rest of your application.

Comment: This is complete, and a borderline Cthulhu-solution. :)

Comment: I also posted this on the OpenJFX mailing list, and was pointed to these two open bug reports for tracking this.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091107
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091517

With luck, at some point in the future these will be closed and there will be much more elegant solution, ha.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX does not use AWT to create the window, as opposed to Swing.

---

You could embed a JavaFX `Scene` into a Swing application, like this:

```
// On EDT:
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.setContentPane(jfxPanel);

// On JavaFX Application Thread:
jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(...));
```

Then, `JFrame` extends `java.awt.Frame` which is a `java.awt.Window`.